# Limits on the size of std::exception_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11

I would like to know just how big these can get, or if anyone has encountered something absurd along these lines.

The one in the VCRT is a workable 2 pointers, but I have a fixed message block size* to work with, and I'm worried that, whilst porting sometime in the future, I might get slapped with something obnoxious (like cacheline-sized mutexes and other fun things).

*within 64 bytes or a cacheline, whichever is smaller.

Comment: VTC as *too broad*. An authoritative answer would require someone to look through all standard library implementations to see how they define this type. Your best bet is to enforce a maximum size, whatever you deem sane, using a `static_assert`. If you ever have to compile your code on a platform where that fails, then deal with it as necessary.

Comment: Agreed. I have `static_assert`s all over the place already. It is a shame that there aren't any reasonable restrictions -- where it is now, it would be a big problem to work around if it were to break...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are only 3 implementations of `std::exception_ptr` I know of.  You've measured one:

vc++ == 2 pointers

Here's libc++:  1 pointer.

Here's gcc:  https://ideone.com/0Pirmt 1 pointer.